# Android app limit question?

Tags: android

Is there a limit on number of apps you are allowed to upload to android market after you pay the 25 dollar registration fee? Or is it 25 dollars for each different app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you pay the one-time registration fee ($25), you can upload as many apps as you want.

http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit (within reason).  Once you've paid the $25 dollars you can upload as many as you like.  However, Google has removed a few developers who flooded the market with thousands of apps.

Answer (score 1):

No it's just a one time fee you have to pay in order to get registered as a developer who is allowed to distribute apps on the Market.